# Установка Windows 8.1 на Macbook Pro 2012 в режиме EFI

Tags: windows, macos, администрирование, установка

Здравствуйте!

Проблема состоит в следующем. 
Имеется компьютер Macbook Pro 2012 сер. 2012 г. На нем стоит OS X El Capitan с последними обновлениями.
Мне необходимо установить на компьютер в качестве второй (не виртуализация) ОС Windows 8.1, причем чтобы имелось возможность из под Windows 8.1 размечать дополнительные разделы. Например, для потребностей ОС и системного ПО был "Локальный диск C",а для прочего "Локальный диск D". 
При этом на другом разделе стояла OS X. То есть это обычная ситуация, когда для рабочих целей используется Windows.

Однако такое возможно только, если Windows установлена в режиме EFI. Такой режим, как вам известно, позволяет размечать диск чуть ли не до 100 разделов. Но в этом у меня есть загвоздка.

Я устанавливаю Windows на Mac НЕ с помощью Bootcamp, который встроен в OS X и устанавливает Windows на диск, при этом эмулируя BIOS. Я использую загрузочную флешку, при этом загружаю последние обновления для поддержки ПО Apple - Bootcamp,  также на флешку, чтобы затем после установки Windows установить и драйвера.
После загрузки флешки я выбираю режим EFI ("EFI Boot" он кажется называется). Дальнейшая установка производится без особых проблем и нестандартных ситуаций.

После установки системы я ставлю драйвера, которые также вроде без проблем устанавливаются. ОДНАКО после установки драйверов и перезагрузки компьютера драйвер "Контроллер High Definition Audio"  от Microsoft в дипетчере устройств отображается как некорректно установленный (восклицательный знак), при этом в описании там же значится ошибка "код 10", эта общий вид ошибки и в чем конкретно ошибка я не понял. Соответственно не работает звук на компьютере, хотя все остальное в норме.

В чем же может быть проблема? Я вручную загружал последние драйвера звука от Realtek и для видео Intel HD graphics 4000, но это не помогло. 
Я пробовал вообще полностью стирать диск (вместе с OS X), затем создавать разделы, ставить сначала Windows а потом OS X, но и это не помогло.

Также пробовал вручную ставить драйвера звука -  Cirrus Logic, также не помогло.

Пожалуйста, как мне разрешить эту проблему? Может при установке системы требуется что-то еще? На зарубежных форумах читал, что возможно надо ставить альтернативный загрузчик, что то типа refind, но с этим я не очень разобрался...

Прошу, если у кого-нибудь есть идеи, поделитесь...

Comment: немного не ясно зачем вам дял работы винда в загрузке, но ладно. Действительно вам нужно установить альтернативный загрузчик  www.cmd-help.ru/установка-загрузчика-clover-efi/

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1098265/windows-10-efi-installation-in-mbp-8-2-without-bootcamp
this is fully explayn about this mac, win, efi problem.